# Adding element to another element win forms

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

I am adding one panel to another panel it works but circle which is in inspanel not shown. how can i solved this. 
I am using below code. It works but not show circle

```
    public static int xTemp = 0;
    public static int yTemp = 0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel insPanel = new Panel();
        Random xRandom = new Random();
        xTemp= xRandom.Next(20,100);
        Random yRandom = new Random();
        yTemp = yRandom.Next(20, 100);
        insPanel.Location = new Point(xTemp, yTemp);
        insPanel.Width=40;
        insPanel.Height = 40;
        insPanel.Visible = true;
        insPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        insPanel.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(insPanel_Paint);
        panel1.Controls.Add(insPanel);

    }

    void insPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics =this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, new Rectangle(xTemp,yTemp, 10, 10));
        myBrush.Dispose();
        formGraphics.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue: you're trying to draw your circle at wrong coordinates.

`xTemp` and `yTemp` are coordinates of `insPanel` relative to `panel1`. But when you drawing your circle, you should use coordinates relative to panel you're drawing at - `insPanel`.

Another issue: there is no need to create and dispose graphics each time you're drawing something on your panel. You can use `e.Graphics` from `Paint` eventhandler arguments.

Based on above, your code could look like:

```
void insPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10));
    }
}
```

Also note - since paint event can occur very frequently, it could be a good idea not to create and dispose brush every time, but use brush cached in your class private field.

Comment: thanks korneyev, i want to ask one another question. I am writing a windows form app. And i am waiting for this when circle this the frame it should change the route and i am doing timer to change circle location.

Comment: @altandogan Your "another question" is hard to understand, but it seems unrelated to the original question. It is better to ask it as another question (not comment),and in that question provide more explanation, code you've tried and problems you've faced.

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.Graphics` instead of `this.CreateGraphics`:

```
System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = e.Graphics;
```

One more issue is you're getting coordinates in range of `20 - 100` (`xRandom.Next(20,100)`) and your panel dimensions are just `40, 40`.